# Categories problem conditional

Tags: categories

In channel entries tag I have something like this

{if category =="39|50|51"}
   do this
{if:else}
   do that
{/if}

if statement is not working. I do not get it why. there are no variables for channel entries so I presume that is part of the problem. But how to do it then? How to check if entry has category to display one message, if it has another display something else

Edit with full tag:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="katalog" limit="12" dynamic="yes" status="open" show_future_entries="no" orderby="date" sort="desc" disable="member_data" pagination="bottom"}

{if category =="39|50|51"}

{exp:channel_images:images entry_id="{entry_id}" channel="katalog" limit="1" cover_only="yes"}
show image

{if image:no_images}
show alternative image that says NO IMAGE found
{/if}
{/exp:channel_images:images}

{if:else}
show something completely else for entries that are not in category 39, 50 or 51
{/if}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Can you add a full code snippet including the channel entries tag? Your example is hard to debug since there is no "category" variable for the entries tag.

Comment: I edited question with full tag